# utlrp.sql fails to execute

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, recompile

I just created a docker image of Oracle 11g ee following this tutorial https://vitalflux.com/how-to-install-oracle-11g-ee-on-docker/ and loaded some tables inside.

The process worked fine and no errors happens during the load of a huge sql file (10K+) with sqlplus. But on the last step the process breaks. I could pinpoint the issue to the following line for recompilation:

```
@?/rdbms/admin/utlrp.sql
```

The error received is the following:

```
ERRORS DURING RECOMPILATION
---------------------------
                          0


Function created.

   p_schemaname  dbms_id;
                 *
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-06550: line 5, column 18:
PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_ID' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 5, column 18:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 6, column 18:
PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_ID' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 6, column 18:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 62, column 34:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or
malformed
ORA-06550: line 62, column 12:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 65, column 33:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or
malformed
ORA-06550: line 64, column 12:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored



Function dropped.
```

I tried to find an answer on google but the best I could find is that there are some invalid objects. Which I couldn't find any.

```
SQL> SELECT owner,
  2         object_type,
  3         object_name,
  4         status
  5  FROM   dba_objects
  6  WHERE  status = 'INVALID'
  7  ORDER BY owner, object_type, object_name;

no rows selected
```

I am executing the process as sys with sysdba. Maybe the re-compilation is not necessary but I cannot remove it from the script.

A week ago I tried to do the same thing on a "real" Oracle 11g installation without docker. There the script worked. So I assume that there is something wrong with the container but I am not sure what exactly.

Did anybody encounter this issue before, do you have any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Version

```
SQL> select * from v$version;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.1.0      Production
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
```

Comment: 11.2.0.1 is seriously bugged.  Use 11.2.0.4.  Better yet, go for 18c/19c version.

Comment: @MichaelKutz, would love to :) I have already have a 12c image and it works. Unfortunately the customer has 11 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DBMS_ID` is a subtype in `DBMS_STANDARD` starting with version 12c.

`DBMS_ID` does not exist in 11g.

You have a messed up environment with 12c scripts and a 11g database.

The code that fails is in `$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/reenable_indexes.sql`, which is called by `$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/utlprp.sql`, which is called by `$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/utlrp.sql`.

This is an environmental issue but we do not know what you have done so far. In a properly created and configured environment this would not happen.

If you want to use 11g, look for a 11g image. There must have been someone desperate enough to create one. Like this one: [docker-oracle-ee-11g](https://hub.docker.com/r/sath89/docker-oracle-ee-11g). No, I haven't tested it.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. The explanation really helps. I tried the same with the image you linked in your answer. Unfortunately I experience the same error message with the other image. It seems like all db objects were correctly created. Do you maybe have an idea what else could be wrong?

Comment: @Oldfighter I tested docker container from the link provided by Balazs it works fine.Invalidated an object and ran recompilation without any errors.

Comment: @Oldfighter Let me guess. You connect to the 11g database remotely from somewhere else, where a 12c database is installed, and you executed `@?/rdbms/admin/utlrp.sql` in that session, and not locally inside the container. This syntax calls scripts local to the client, not the server, so the scripts are executed from the local 12c ORACLE_HOME, and not the 11g ORACLE_HOME installed in the container. If this the case, I suggest using `DBMS_UTILITY.COMPILE_SCHEMA` on the schema you work with, instead of running `utlrp`. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_util.htm#i1002332

Comment: @BalazsPapp, that was it. I tested it and it works. Thank you very much, this saved me so much time and effort!